# Increasing number when reacting to message (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a variable in a json file increase, when a certain person reacts to a message in discord, that my bot sent (the reaction is already made by the discord bot if that matters).

Comment: Would `variable_name+=1` work?

Comment: Please include your code/what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add) event

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.id == your_message_id:
        if reaction.emoji == your_emoji:
            # update the number
```